# Unity ScreenToWorldPoint returning behind camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, raycasting

In unity, I am using ScreenToWorldPoint to move my object with my mouse, but the DrawRay from my transform to the ScreenPoint returns behind my camera for some reason. I've tried testing and finding out the reason but I just have no idea; here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScreenToWorldPointTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject obj;
    public Vector3 objDist;
    public Vector3 objDistFwd;
    public float moveSpeed = .1f;

    void Start() {
        obj = GameObject.Find("ChessKnightWhite");
    }

    void Update() {
        Vector3 objPos = obj.transform.position;
        objDist = objPos - transform.position;
        objDistFwd = new Vector3(objDist.x * transform.forward.x, objDist.y * transform.forward.y, objDist.z * transform.forward.z);
        Vector3 screenPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, objDistFwd.magnitude)
        Vector3 move = Vector3.lerp(screenPoint, transform.position, moveSpeed);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, screenPoint, Color.Green);

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            obj.transform.position = move - new Vector3(0, .5f, 0);
            }
    }
}
```

and usually, this works fine; the ray ends at the object (well, not at the object if it's being moved, but if it (the mouse) is still it would be at the object) and the object moves whenever and wherever I want it to, keeping the same distance from me (forwardly, where it's not the same distance but, say, the transform is normal (0, 0, 1), it will stay at 1 on the z-axis). But sometimes (observed at camera/player is at 0, 15, -10 -- with a rotation of 60 on the x -- and the object is at 0, 1, 0) the ray is behind me! and what's even weirder, is instead of going to where the Ray ends, it stays a little bit in front of the camera?! I thought, "maybe the z on ScreenToWorldPoint is negative?", but it cant be, because the x, z, and y are squared and added together to get magnitude. and printing it out even confirms this, but for some reason, it changes when I move the mouse sometimes. I have no idea what's causing this, so any insight would be very helpful (please also, if you can, include an explanation or any information as to why this might happen).

Comment: debug the values, get it showing your objpos, the objdist and so on.. you'll probably soon spot whats not what you thought

Comment: When you calculate `objDistFwd` did you mean to say `objDistFwd = transform.forward * objDist.magnitude`? You want to scale the forward vector by the distance to the object right? If that's the case you can use `objDist.magnitude` instead of `objDistFwd.magnitude` they are identical.

Comment: If you wanted to get the distance between you and obj why not simply use [`Vector3.Distance(obj.transform.position, transform.position)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) ?

Comment: @Pluto , no, i want to multiply it so that the distance from it forwardly will be different from the distance, so if i have the distance of 5, 0, 1; and im facing world forward 0, 0, 1; then i want the distance to be 1, because its 1 away from me on the z axis, which is the direction im facing, if i did magnitude * my forward, it would be 3.3(and more stuff) so the distance magnitude will be different than the objDistFwd magnitude and even if i did it the way you said the magnitudes will be different, and not what i want anyway

Comment: @derHugo , the distance calculations are fine, that will do the same thing, my problem is that the screentoworldpoint, the worldpoint is behind me for some reason

Comment: @BugFinder, I believe I already tried that, but ill try again

Comment: @GreatnessGamers So you want the length of the distance vector projected on the forward vector. That is `Vector3.Dot(objDist, transform.forward)`. This can be negative if the object is behind the camera.

Comment: @Pluto i dont want the total length of the distance vector, i dont think ive communicated this correctly (sorry, but please bear with me, ive been told i might have aspergers)
basically, imagine your looking straight, and you want something to be moved only side to side, and stay where it is forward and backward, if you took the magnitude of it times your forward (IE its distance has a magnitude of sqrt(26) [dist is 5, 0, 1]) and your forward is default (0, 0, 1), then it would move it on the z axis when you set its transform, so it would go farther away from you forward/backward

Comment: @GreatnessGamers The [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection)  gives you the length of the projection in this case since the forward vector is a unit vector, not the length of the distance.

Comment: @Pluto cont. what i want to do is keep it the same distance away from me forward and backward, but move it side to side (so if im facing forward, then i want to keep its position on the z axis the same, and move it on the x axis (left/right if not default forward) and the y axis (up/down if not default forward)
the thing is, im using the magnitude, which will always be positive, due to squareing/square rooting, so why is the screentoworldpoint behind the camera

EDIT: sorry it took so long, in class

Comment: @Pluto but what would I use that for? if the objDist is (0, -4.33012701892, 2.5) and the forward is x-60 (for the real thing it would be, instead of unity having the y at -.9 for some reason) (0, -.866025403784, .5) then the magnitude of the distance would be 5, and multiplying that by the cosine in degrees of the 60 degree rotation (.5) would equal 2.5, and I need it to be 5 on the distance for the screentoworldpoint.

Comment: @GreatnessGamers I think you misunderstood me. `depth = Vector3.Dot(objDist, transform.forward)` is the dot product, and it gives you the depth (the distance in the forward direction) of the object with respect to the camera. You can use this in `ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, depth))`

Comment: @Pluto i think i understand now, but i dont understand how the dot product in unity actually works, as it states it multiplies the magnitudes of the 2 together and multiplies that by the cosine  between the 2 angles, and while i have several questions of what "between the 2 angles" means (such as if it is different on every axis, which angle would it use, as it forms a 3d pyramid) but how would that give the distance of it?

Comment: @Pluto okay, so, after doing some research and testing, I found out that the dot product of a vector is the same as what I did here, (xa * xb, ya * yb, za * zb), and the unity docs were wrong. what a surprise, I mean its not like half of all the unity docs are wrong /s
anyway, I believe I found the problem, and a solution (albeit not ideal), which I shall be posting and explaining as an answer after further testing and confirmation.

Comment: @Pluto nevermind about the solution, turns out what i thought was the cause wasnt

Comment: @Pluto sorry pluto, im stupid. all I had to do is think about the thing and I looked at it and u were right. thank you

Answer (score 1):

so after a while I realized that Pluto was right, I needed to use dot product instead of the magnitude of (xa * xb, ya * yb, za * zb). Sorry Pluto, thanks for your help and your patience with me